# grid.js - export data from grid do csv, txt

Tags: export, export-to-csv, grid.js

Is any possible to add export data from grid.js to any format (CSV or TXT).
Can someone help me with code that is simple for a PHP programmer to implement?

My simple demo on codepen: https://codepen.io/marcif/pen/KKEjgXE

I can't find any example online on how to do this

```
new gridjs.Grid({
    columns: ["Name", "Email", "Phone Number", "Gender"],
    sort: true,
    data: [
          ["Dirk", "dborkett0@com.com", "(646) 3432270", "Male"],
          ["Maryl", "mchampkins1@dailymail.co.uk", "(980) 3335235", "Female"],
          ["Stefan", "sbrawson2@smh.com.au", "(180) 3533257", "Male"],
          ["Stephanie", "scouronne4@storify.com", "(904) 5358792", "Female"],
          ["Emeline", "esooley5@cyberchimps.com", "(308) 6561908", "Female"],
          ["Gavra", "gkrout9@foxnews.com", "(383) 4909639", "Female"],
          ["Roxi", "rvillage1@businessweek.com", "(980) 3335235", "Male"],
          ["Jamey", "jsheringham0@rakuten.co.jp", "(773) 5233571", "Male"],
          ["Maye", "mambrosoni8@prweb.com", "(895) 9997017", "Female"]
        ]
}).render(document.getElementById("table"));
```